# git clone from WebDav

Tags: git, apache, webdav

I want to have a portable git environment, so I can move it to different machine when needed.

I have XAMPP Portable and Git portable. I have enabled WebDav on XAMPP and confirmed it is working. I can copy and write to that folder via WebDav client (Carrot Dav in my case).

Using git portable i created a blank project called "test" and added a single "main.c" file to test.

Now I want to clone "test" project over the network. So on another PC i run

```
git clone http://myserver.com/git/test
```

and I get:

```
fatal: repository 'http://myserver.com/git/test/' not found
```

I can clone it if I specify SMB folder location, but unfortunately it will not work from WebDav.  I have tried: https, include username, password and both in URL with same results. I run everything as administrator so there is no permission issues. If I check Apache logs, I cannot see this:

```
192.168.1.9 - - [18/Dec/2013:15:49:44 +0000] "GET /test/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 404 1049
```

I am now stuck and unsure what I'm missing here.

Update:
I did as per suggestion in 'duplicate' but get exactly the same results. I am ready to pay someone to answer this. Free money! Anyone?

Comment: I have done as per your link, and no change. Anyone has any better suggestions? Anyone managed to setup git server under XAMPP?

Comment: anyone? @Kate-Gregory